# XslCompiledTransform eats my DOCTYPE

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, doctype

Made a xslt template with output instruction for `<DOCTYPE>`:

```
<xsl:output media-type="text/html" method="html" encoding="windows-1251" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```

In xsl-debug I'm receiving right

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

on top of the html.

But when I'm using XslCompiledTransform etc.. output starts from

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

So, DOCTYPE is missed. Why? Right properties of `XslCompiledTransform` initialized just like I set in `<xsl:output>` .

Code:

```
using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    XmlEmbeddedResourceResolver resolver = new XmlEmbeddedResourceResolver();
    xslt.Load("clires://DLLPATH/xsl/blank.xsl", XsltSettings.TrustedXslt, resolver);
    XmlWriterSettings set = new XmlWriterSettings();
    set.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;
    xslt.Transform(ticket, XmlWriter.Create(sw, set));
    return sw.ToString();
}
```

How can I get DOCTYPE from XslCompiledTransform?

Comment: Please post the code you use to call the transform.

Comment: done! (blablabla for 15 chars rule)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `XmlWriterSettings` from the [OutputSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.outputsettings) property in `XslCompiledTransform`

```
XmlWriterSettings set = xslt.OutputSettings;
```